# UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

How can I make a Modal View's presentation style UIModalPresentationFormSheet (or something what looks like it) on an iPhone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't using the built-in frameworks.

You'll have to write your own code to show a view modally that doesn't fully obscure the underlying view, unless someone else has already done that and released it publicly.

Comment: Off the top of my head? Create a top-level view with a transparent background, and then have a child subview with an opaque background sized smaller than the top-level view. This would be the view for a MyModalViewController class. Add a property that takes a `UIViewController` and a custom setter that takes its `view` and assigns it to that inner view inside the top-level one. You'd present this view controller modally using the usual `presentModalViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 1):

You also might wanna checkout the following open source project:

https://github.com/KitchenStories/charleene

Comment: It works but a better design would make use of a custom UIPresentationController subclass since that is what they were created for: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html