# Duplicating Twitterrific Style Alert

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uistoryboard

[image]

I am trying to replicate the screen in the middle, namely the alert that is displayed to compose a new tweet. I have tried to duplicate it with a custom `UIAlertView` but that requires a lot of subclassing and what not, then I suspected it might just be a simple `UIViewController` that is displayed over the main view... professional thoughts from fellow iOS developers is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: The screen in the middle? It's not an UIAlertView... It should be a custom UIView. Well, if it's for tweeting, should you use the Twitter API from iOS SDK ?

Comment: No, I am using it for something else, yeah I figured it would be a UIView, but do you know how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In iPad:**

You can do it with a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

- You need to design UI according to the above image.
- Then you need to set the Modal Presentation Style to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`
- And present it using `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))`

Like:

```
UIViewController *viewC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewC.view.frame = //set the frame;
viewC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:viewC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**In iPhone:**

You can do it with using a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

You can use the following code for doing this:

*Declare a property in your interface*

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *views;
```

*//Add the view*

```
- (void) showView
{
   UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 35)];
        UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(remove)];
        toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:bar];
        _views = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -300, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/3)];
        [_views addSubview:toolbar];
        [_views setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:_views];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{

                             _views.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/3);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL yes){
                             NSLog(@"YO");

                         }];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

*//Remove the view*

```
- (void)remove
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         _views.frame = CGRectMake(0, -500, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/3);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL yes){
                         NSLog(@"YA");

                     }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I fiddled with the frame of the view controller, but it always displays over the entire the view instead of being displayed as an overlay for the main view controller.

Comment: @Ravin455: did you set the frame ?

Comment: @Ravin455: Check the styles [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Comment: I think that only works with the iPad. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702653/uimodalpresentationformsheet-on-iphone though, that I think is the answer to my question.

Comment: @Ravin455: yeah, I see. I done a sample code for doing some similar stuff. I'll update my answer. Please check

Comment: I am getting this as an error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
      ___30-[MasterViewController remove]_block_invoke in MasterViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 Do you know how to counter it?

Comment: @Ravin455: you need to declare a property in your interface like: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *views;`

Comment: @Ravin455: Is that what you want ?